# Match multiple occurrences in the string Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to match regex to match multiple occurrences in the same string.
The pattern is alphabets then zero or more numbers,alphabets,colon then forward slash then one or more numbers,alphabets then backward slash then again one or more numbers,alphabets

for example
`w:/a\bc::/12\xyz` should give me occurrences as 8.

I tried the following code

```
Regex a11 = new Regex(@"([a-z]+[a-z1-9:]+/[a-z1-9]+\\[a-z1-9]+)+");
Regex a1 = new Regex(@"([a-z]+/[a-z1-9]+\\[a-z1-9]+)+");
var a = a11.Matches(@"w:/a\bc::/12\\xyz");
```

but it matches only one time even if multiple occurrences. Also in the pattern second character is optional so I have declared two regex . Is there a way to do everything in a single regex. Any help is much appreciated

"a" has only one match.

Comment: Show the rest of your code that uses the Regex variables.

Comment: You have not provided us with enough information to be able to help you. Please edit your post giving us more code to be able to help you figure this out :) You may want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated my code

Comment: Please explain why there are eight occurrences in `w:/a\bc::/12\xyz`. Please list them.

Comment: first w:/a\b 
second w:/a\bc
third bc::/12\x
fourth bc::/12\xy
fifth bc::/12\xyz
sixth c::/12\x
seventh c::/12\xy
eight c::/12\xyz

so eight occurance..

Comment: @saravana14 You will have to generate all possible substrings and then run the regex to check if there is a match.  A regex cannot match several times at the same location inside the string.

Comment: any tips on how generate to substrings? because there are so many combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate all substrings from your input string that start from one and the same positions and then use your pattern enclosed with `^` and `$` anchors to test for the whole string match.

Here is a way to do that:

```
var s = "w:/a\\bc::/12\\xyz";
var r = new Regex(@"^\p{L}+[\p{L}\d:]*/[\p{L}\d]+\\[\p{L}\d]+$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
for (var q = 0; q < s.Length; ++q)
    for (var w = q; w <= s.Length; ++w)
    {
        var cur = s.Substring(q, w-q);
        if (r.IsMatch(cur))
            Console.WriteLine("FOUND: {0}", cur);
    }
```

Output:

```
FOUND: w:/a\b
FOUND: w:/a\bc
FOUND: bc::/12\x
FOUND: bc::/12\xy
FOUND: bc::/12\xyz
FOUND: c::/12\x
FOUND: c::/12\xy
FOUND: c::/12\xyz
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/tWtdXU).

The pattern is

```
^\p{L}+[\p{L}\d:]*/[\p{L}\d]+\\[\p{L}\d]+$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{L}+` - 1+ letters
- `[\p{L}\d:]*` - 0+ letters, digits or/and `:`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[\p{L}\d]+` - 1+ letters or/and digits
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `[\p{L}\d]+` - 1+ letters or/and digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mu64bX/1).

**NOTE**: To only match ASCII letters, replace `\p{L}` with `[a-zA-Z]` everywhere in the pattern, `@"^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\d:]*/[a-zA-Z\d]+\\[a-zA-Z\d]+$"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> commands = new List<string>()
        {
            @"w\\//a/b",
            @"w\\//a\b",
            @"w\\/a\b",
            @"w:://a\b",
            @"w::/a\b",
            @"w:/a\bc::/12\xyz"
        };

        var titlist = commandCount(commands);
        foreach (var value in titlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    public static List<int> commandCount(List<string> commands)
    {
        List<int> lengths = new List<int>();
        foreach (var command in commands)
        {
            var count = 0;
            var substring = GetAllSubstring(command);
            for (int i = 0; i < substring.Count; i++)
            {
                string input = substring[i];
                Regex r1 = new Regex(@"^[a-z]{1}\w*\:*\/\w+\\[a-z]+$");
                Match match = r1.Match(input);
                if (match.Success)
                    count += match.Groups.Count;
            }
            lengths.Add(count);
        }

        return lengths;
    }

    static List<string> GetAllSubstring(string command)
    {
        List<string> substrings = new List<string>();
        char[] array = command.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sub = new StringBuilder(array[i].ToString());
            substrings.Add(sub.ToString());
            for (int j = i+1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                substrings.Add(sub.Append(array[j]).ToString());
            }
        }

        return substrings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer wold be improved by adding some explanation, not just code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer